# Slow boot time on Dell XPS 9550 with Juno?

Tags: boot, uefi, time, dell

I am just wondering if this is normal or something is weird. To be fair, even Ubuntu 18.10 wasn't the quickest boot around the block, at 40ish seconds. I have an SSD though, I thought it would have been quicker and I hear around booting time in the 10th of seconds.

I am booting via UEFI, thank you!

```
systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 10.867s (firmware) + 7.574s (loader) + 36.980s (kernel) + 1.222s (userspace) = 56.645s
graphical.target reached after 994ms in userspac

systemd-analyze blame
           540ms apt-daily-upgrade.service
           338ms dev-mapper-elementary\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device
           275ms systemd-resolved.service
           240ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           215ms systemd-logind.service
           214ms apparmor.service
           207ms pantheon-parental-controls.service
           180ms plymouth-start.service
           179ms NetworkManager.service
           178ms plymouth-read-write.service
           139ms snapd.service
           137ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           109ms lvm2-pvscan@259:2.service
           107ms networkd-dispatcher.service
            94ms lightdm.service
            92ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
            77ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
            71ms udisks2.service
            70ms ModemManager.service
            69ms systemd-rfkill.service
            60ms accounts-daemon.service
            55ms keyboard-setup.service
            54ms upower.service
            40ms systemd-journald.service
            36ms speech-dispatcher.service
            33ms user@1000.service
            32ms lvm2-monitor.service
            29ms packagekit.service
            29ms gpu-manager.service
            29ms grub-common.service
            28ms pppd-dns.service
            25ms wpa_supplicant.service
            25ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-FB53\x2d02B3.service
            24ms systemd-udevd.service
            21ms thermald.service
            21ms avahi-daemon.service
            17ms systemd-modules-load.service
            17ms bluetooth.service
            16ms colord.service
            15ms polkit.service
            12ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
            11ms setvtrgb.service
            10ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
            10ms kerneloops.service
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out that two big culprits of the slow boot, at least on my Dell XPS 9550, were the LVM and encryption that I turned on during install.

It seems that with some SSD models, this causes a bug that adds up time at boot. I reinstalled without checking those those boxes and boot times are as follows, around 30 seconds less:

```
Startup finished in 17.153s (firmware) + 7.527s (loader) + 5.377s (kernel) + 919ms (userspace) = 30.977s
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is fairly normal. I have an XPS 15 9560 with an i7-7700HQ and systemd-analyze time quotes 44.335s but a big chunk of mine (like 6 seconds) is waiting for the NetworkManager to do its stuff.

I do dual boot and (exceedingly rarely) have actually booted into Windows. The time to get past the log in prompt seems no better (and then I start to panic because I have no idea what to do next...).

I have disabled services until I had a minimal set up to see if that made a difference and I got it down to around 25 seconds but then I couldn't do any real work. I would suggest that you disable as much as possible and see if it makes a difference for you.

Comment: Thank you for getting back. It's not like I NEED for it to be quick, I was just wondering if it was normal or something was wrong. Juno is my second experiment in the Linux world (first being Ubuntu) and I think I was expecting an almost instant boot or something, especially with UEFI; while in reality, Juno UEFI is booting slower than Ubuntu Legacy. I just have Juno on this PC, no dual-boot and BIOS is the latest version, 1.9.0. As for disabling services... I am still not confident enough, I am sure I will end up messing up something. :)